# How do I select same name JSON objects? C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

This is my first question on here so please be patient with me. I am trying to select the first 3 station codes within this JSON and make them into strings in C#:

```
"stations": [
{
  "station_code": "HWV",
  "atcocode": null,
  "tiploc_code": "HTRWTM5",
  "name": "Heathrow Airport   Terminal 5",
  "mode": "train",
  "longitude": -0.490589,
  "latitude": 51.470051,
  "distance": 369
},{
  "station_code": "HXX",
  "atcocode": null,
  "tiploc_code": "HTRWAPT",
  "name": "Heathrow Airport   Central Terminal Area (T123)",
  "mode": "train",
  "longitude": -0.454333,
  "latitude": 51.471404,
  "distance": 2309
}, {
  "station_code": "HAF",
  "atcocode": null,
  "tiploc_code": "HTRWTM4",
  "name": "Heathrow Airport   Terminal 4",
  "mode": "train",
  "longitude": -0.445463,
  "latitude": 51.458266,
  "distance": 3336
}
```

And this is my C# code:

```
dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(localJson);
dynamic LocalDepartTimes = array.stations;

foreach (var station_code in LocalDepartTimes)
{
    string station1 = station_code["station_code"];
    string station2 = station_code["station_code"];
    string station3 = station_code["station_code"];
}
```

I know this is not correct but I am wondering how can I select each station code from the JSON list into 3 separate strings. Thank you!

Comment: Please include the actual JSON in the question, screenshots can be helpful at times but having the actual code in front of you makes it easier for people to help.

Comment: I agree, it would be better to include the JSON as a text, not an image.

Comment: Sorry, new to stackoverflow, made it into text now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) deserializes the JSON into an object (as the name suggests), not an array. See the second example.

#### First example

You can also use the [`JObject.Parse`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/m_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject_parse.htm) which is a bit easier, but without any JSON structure validation, so you should always check if a field you're going to use exists:

```
var stationCodes = new List<string>();

var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(localJson);

foreach (var station in jsonObject["stations"])
{
    Console.WriteLine((string) station["station_code"]);

    stationCodes.Add(station["station_code"].ToString());
}
```

#### Second example

It's a little bit more complicated way using the [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm), but JSON is validated against those objects and their fields, so if the object deserialization has been successful, you can be sure that all fields exist.

```
class Station
{
    public string station_code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    // other fields...
}

class Model
{
    public IList<object> stations { get; set; }
    // other fields...
}

var stationCodes = new List<string>();

var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(localJson);

foreach (var stationCode in jsonObject.stations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(station.station_code);

    stationCodes.Add(station.station_code);
}
```

Also, I don't know what you're going to do with those data next, but what you're doing in your `foreach` loop is overwriting the same variable in each iteration, so at the end, you would have data from the last element only.

Comment: I am going to use each individual station code to then display a time table for each train station, do you know how i can get each unique station code without overwriting variables? Or have gone about this completley wrong?!

Comment: @kieron First example is is much simpler, but without validation of JSON's structure. Instead of printing to console, you can add station codes to the list in the `foreach` loop for example.

Comment: You don't have to thank me for that, it's enough satisfaction if you up-vote my answer ;) Anyway I'm glad it helped you. I'm sure you'll be able to modify it to get first 3 stations only and to put them into a list or something.

Comment: Still trying, but once I have I will put it up on here :)

Comment: Do you know how I would go about putting the sation codes into a list in the foreach loop?

Comment: @kieron Sure, check my answer now.